# Problema al obtener valor de una variable VB.net

Tags: vb.net

veran tengo una funcion que se encarga de mover un motor lineal, para ello comparo dos valores y en caso de que sean iguales se ejecute la funcion de movimiento.

```vb
While contador1 <= total1

    MsgBox("")

    If slide1 = desde Then
        TrySetTarget(0, hasta)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    End If

    If slide1 = hasta Then
        TrySetTarget(0, desde)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        contador1 = contador1 + 1
        If TextBox15.Text <= 1 Then
            contador1 = contador1 + 2
            TextBox15.Text = TextBox15.Text - 1
        Else
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            TextBox15.Text = TextBox15.Text - 1

        End If
    End If




End While
```

La funcion de arriba se encarga de mover el motor y esta:

```vb
Sub TryGetVariables()

    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String


    Dim gf1 As String
    Dim gt1 As String
    Try
        Using device As Usc = connectToDevice() ' Find a device and temporarily connect.


            device.getVariables(st1)


            galfaf1 = st1(1).position
            galfat1 = st1(2).position


            slide1 = st1(0).position
            valor = Me.slide1

            a = (5 * galfaf1) / 1023
            b = (5 * galfat1) / 1023


            c = 0.1 * (slide1 / 4 - 1000)



            If a >= 0 And a <= 0.1 Then
                gf1 = 19.23 * a
                'MsgBox(gf1)
                TextBox5.Text = gf1
            ElseIf a > 0.1 And a <= 1.3 Then
                gf1 = 19.23 * a + 25
                'MsgBox(gf1)
                TextBox5.Text = gf1
            ElseIf a > 1.3 And a <= 2.5 Then
                gf1 = 225 * (a - 1.3) + 50
                'MsgBox(gf1)
                TextBox5.Text = gf1
            ElseIf a > 2.5 And a <= 3.4 Then
                gf1 = 755.5 * (a - 2.5) + 320
                'MsgBox(gf1)
                TextBox5.Text = gf1
            End If

            If b >= 0 And b <= 0.1 Then
                gt1 = 19.23 * b
                TextBox12.Text = gt1
            ElseIf b > 0.1 And b <= 1.3 Then
                gt1 = 19.23 * b + 25
                TextBox12.Text = gt1
            ElseIf b > 1.3 And b <= 2.5 Then
                gt1 = 225 * (b - 1.3) + 50
                TextBox12.Text = gt1
            ElseIf b > 2.5 And b <= 3.4 Then
                gt1 = 755.5 * (b - 2.5) + 320
                TextBox12.Text = gt1
            End If

            TrackBar1.Value = c


            ' device.Dispose() is called automatically when the "Using" block ends,
            ' allowing other functions and processes to use the device.
        End Using
    Catch exception As Exception  ' Handle exceptions by displaying them to the user.
        displayException(exception)
    End Try
End Sub
```

La funcion TryGetVariables() se va ejecutando mediante un Timer cada 50 milisegundos y slider1, la variable que me da problemas se va refrescando en la misma, mi problema es que cuando la utilizo en el codigo de arriba del todo no obtiene valor y solo cuando pongo un MsgBox, obtiene valor y el motor se mueve, he intentado de todo, colocando la funcion dentro del primer cacho de codigo y no utilizar el Timer pero no me funciona correctamente porque no realiza toda la funcionalidad del codigo. No se que hacer por mucho que le doy vueltas, por favor agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: No es la solucion ideal, pero solo por probar si el problema es el que imagino... Si en tu primer código (dentro del bucle `While`) añades `Application.DoEvents()` notas alguna diferencia?

Comment: No comprendo en que parte del código se encuentra el problema

Comment: @Pikoh Pues si que funciona, de hecho va perfectamente. Me gustaria que me comentaras que problema es el que te imaginas que es, tambien me sirve para ver que es lo que hago mal. Un saludo.

Comment: @som1995 mira mi respuesta, a ver si se entiende :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es una suposición, ya que sin ver todo el código no es fácil analizarlo.

El problema en tu código es el bucle que tienes: `While contador1 <= total1`...

Lo que te está pasando es que ese bucle esta acaparando todo el flujo del programa, no permitiendo que los eventos se disparen y por lo tanto `TryGetVariables` se ejecute. Y como el bucle depende de las variables que se actualizan fuera del bucle, por eso no te funciona correctamente.

Al poner un `MsgBox` o, como en mi comentario te dije, un `Application.DoEvents()`, lo que haces es parar momentaneamente la ejecución del bucle y permitir que todos los eventos que estaban en cola esperando dispararse puedan hacerlo.

Lo lógico es que si dependes del método `TryGetVariables` dentro de ese bucle, lo ejecutes dentro:

```
While contador1 <= total1

    TryGetVariables()

    If slide1 = desde Then
        TrySetTarget(0, hasta)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    End If

   If slide1 = hasta Then
        TrySetTarget(0, desde)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        contador1 = contador1 + 1
        If TextBox15.Text <= 1 Then
            contador1 = contador1 + 2
            TextBox15.Text = TextBox15.Text - 1
        Else
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            TextBox15.Text = TextBox15.Text - 1

        End If
    End If
End While
```

Comment: El problema, si que lo he comentado mas arriba, aunque puede que no me haya explicado correctamente, es que aunque la ponga dentro como tu me estas comentando lamentablemente sucede lo mismo. No ocurre lo mismo que en este caso si no que es otra variable la que no obtiene su valor y por lo tanto es otro cacho de codigo que no se ejecuta correctamente. Viendo lo que sucede debo replantearme el codigo, ya que esto funciona para un motor y necesito 5 en total, no puedo imaginarme lo que sucedera. Te agradezco tu ayuda de verdad, ya no sabia que hacer, mil gracias :).

Comment: Claro,como te digo sin ver todo el código es dificil aconsejarte. Pero por resumir,tienes un problema con bucles que impiden que los eventos se disparen. Tendrás que replantear tu aplicación haciendo uso de eventos y BackGroundWorkers por ejemplo, no suele ser una buena idea tener bucles "semiinfinitos"  que dependan de cosas "del exterior" :)